# WCF Service - Relate Code File to Code Behind File

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am manually reconstructing a WCF service from pieces. I add a MyService.svc file MyService.svc.cs file.

How the heck do I now make the latter the code-behind of the former? It's not just a matter of editing the project file to add the dependency and editing the svc file to point to the code behind file. Neither of those, nor the combination, works for me.

I also tried right click remove from project then include, which I seem to recall used to work for asp.net pages in one or another version of Visual Studio.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and then accept it after a waiting period.  Helpful for other folks that run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just got it to work. Remove from project and then include in project actually does work. The trick is to make sure the files have the same names, except for the extensions. Although I called them both MyService in the question, in fact they had different names which was why it wasn't working.

So:

1. Make sure the roots are the same name.
2. You don't need to edit the project file or the markup file to point to the code behind.
3. Right click and exclude from the project.
4. Ensure Show All Files is active (top of solution explorer)
5. Ctrl-click to select both files.
6. Right click and select include in project.

They will be associated as markup and code behind.